# Allure and Jira X-Ray integration

Tags: allure, jira-xray

Our customer is using Allure and Cypress in his development environment and would like to integrate this environment into Jira X-Ray.

As far as I could read, Allure is processing test result and report. How those test result can be send back to Jira-Ray in order to collect test result metrics in Jira ?

Thanks for your findings, sample will be appreciate as we are new to this

regards

Answer (score 0):

If using Cypress, you can use the report produced by the test runner to integrate with Xray. If you're using Cucumber together with Cypress, you'll use "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor" package; you'll need to decide which [workflow](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62267221#TestinginBDDwithGherkinbasedframeworks(e.g.Cucumber)-Workflows) to adopt. If you're not using Cucumber, then the flow is simpler and you just need to upload the results, usually using a JUnit XML kinda of report.

This is independent on whether you're using Allure or not.

[This tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+using+Cypress+and+Cucumber+in+JavaScript) is for Xray on Jira Cloud but it can easily be adapted if you are using Jira onpremises (server/Datacenter).

Comment: hello @sérgio, I am not able to access the tutorial link you provide, it request a login but I am not able to create one...any direct link ?

Comment: @serge, sorry the tutorial wasn't yet published. It should be now available; I've updated the link on the description